# How to save " in a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, escaping

So I have the following code which doesn't work. I couldn't figure it out how to do it.

```
 std::string str("Q850?51'18.23"");
```

First problem I face is `"` (quotation mark). I cannot save it as a string because at the end of the string I have two `"` characters and C++ doesn't let me save the whole string.

Second I want to split the string and save it in different variables.

E.g.;

```
double i = 850;
double j = 51;
double k = 18.23;
```

Comment: you simply need to google everything. sorry.

Comment: You should read a beginners' guide to the language in order to learn the baseics before trying to work with the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to escape the quotation mark you require in the string;

```
std::string str("Q850?51'18.23\"");
//                            ^ escape the quote here
```

The cppreference site has a list of these [escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Alternatively you are use a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal);

```
std::string str = R"(Q850?51'18.23")";
```

The second part of the problem is dependent on the format and predictability of the data;

- If it is fixed width, a simple index and be used to extract the numbers and convert to the `double` you require.
- If it is delimited with the characters above, you can consume the string to each of the delimiters extracting the numbers in-between them (you should be able to find suitable libraries to assist with this).
- If it is some further unknown composition, you may be limited to consuming the string one character at a time and extracting the numerical values between the non-numerical values.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [escape](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) your quote mark:

```
std::string str("Q850?51'18.23\"");
//                            ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your quote mark

Add a backslash before `"`

```
std::string str("Q850?51'18.23\"");
```